# Проверьте правильность расстановки знаков

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

1. Глава семьи занимался ремонтом машин: хобби, или профессия?
2. Поясню, что означает, не всем понятное, слово «бетель-нат».

Comment: Что же за проверка такая, если у вас нет уверенности в половине случаев? – shampar 6 минут назад

Comment: Так, если бы был уверен, не спрашивал бы... Это же не игра в "угадайку". :-)

Comment: Я про то, что проверяют написанное. Скобки я уберу. Их проверять не надо?

Answer (score 1):

*1. Глава семьи занимался ремонтом машин: хобби или профессия?

2. Поясню, что означает не всем понятное слово «бетель-нат».*

Насчёт двоеточия в первом не уверен. Может, вообще надо перестроить фразу.

Comment: Глава семьи занимался ремонтом машин: то ли хобби, то ли профессия. (Так лучше?)

Comment: Да, лучше. Только вот я не уверен, что такое предложение имеет право на существование. Посмотрел случаи постановки двоеточия, там раскрытие, разъяснение, причина, описание чувств. И вторая часть там как предложение. А "то ли хобби, то ли профессия" — не предложение. С другой стороны сказать вроде так можно, и я представляю соответствующую интонацию. Но как правильно это оформить, не знаю. А вообще, второй вариант по звучанию однозначно лучше и понятнее.

Comment: Глава семьи занимался ремонтом машин - то ли хобби, то ли профессия. (Теперь в порядке?)